# Assigning value to a two dimensional array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, client-server

I have a client server program. The client are the students so I've made a seat plan that generates two dimensional button arrays.

```
Button[,] btnSeat = new Button[8, 6];
```

How can I assign the client's hostname to each button once a client is online? Assuming there is already a hostname. Assign the first user who goes online to the first array[0,0] and the second to array[0,1] and so on....?

This is the layout of my seat plan
[image]

I also need to retrieve array[x,y] that is equals to that hostname. Please help, thank you.

Comment: Additionally it looks like you need to skip columns 3-6 for rows 6 and 7.

Comment: I don't think array is the right data structure here, a dictionary with a "computer" data structure would be more appropriate, using the hostname as the key and the `Computer` holding the row/column position, host name, and whatever data about the station you want.

Comment: it's already taken care of :), i just need a way to assign a certain value and retrieve it until the server stops receiving data

Comment: @RonBeyer I haven't looked into a dictionary. could you please provide me an example with your expanation about "using the hostname as the key and the Computer holding the row/column position" please. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of what I think would be a better data structure:

For the Computer, you need to hold some information, so create a class for the computer:

```
public class Computer
{
    public string HostName { get; set; }
    public int Row { get; set; }
    public int Column { get; set; }
    //Whatever else you want to add, like
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsScrewingAround { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use a dictionary to store the data:

```
public Dictionary<string, Computer> _computers = 
     new Dictionary<string, Computer>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

And you add computers to it like:

```
_computers.Add("someHostName", new Computer() 
    { 
      HostName = "someHostName", 
      Row = 0,  
      Column = 4, 
      IsActive = true, 
      IsScrewingAround = false 
    });
```

Then you can look up Computers by host name in an O(1) operation like:

```
var cpu = _computers["hostName"];
```

Or get a list of computers that are screwing around:

```
var screwOffs = _computers.Values.Where(c => c.IsScrewingAround);
```

Want all the computers in row 4?

```
var row4 = _computers.Values.Where(c => c.Row == 4);
```

This gives you an advantage over an array that it can grow based on the number of `Computer`s added to it in case your room shape changes.

Really this could be a `List<Computer>` if you don't need the O(1) look-up for the host name, which I'm guessing would be fine given the relatively small number of items you have in the classroom.

Comment: this looks neat and easier. by the way can i retain the sets of buttons I made or I have to make another UI?

Comment: You can retain the buttons however you want, even setting an object reference to them in the `Computer`, but I would avoid that so you can separate your business logic from your UI logic.

Comment: hmm i see... i'll look into this more. thank you sir :)